# Rsync download to temporary directory until file is finished, then move to completed directory

Tags: linux, command-line, rsync

So I am trying to wrap my head around rsync. I've been at it now for at least 5 hours straight, but I am not getting any smarter about it. I am connecting to a remote server, trying to download the files from there; to my local machine. The problem is that I get a complete message, but no files have been downloaded, or no changes in directory structure at all. I have read the docs for rsync, and gotten what I believe is the right arguments to pass to rsync. The message I am getting when I run the rsync command is this:

```
sending incremental file list
drwxrwxr-x          4,096 2022/03/20 19:30:59 .

sent 60 bytes  received 64 bytes  248.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

And the command I run is this:

```
sshpass -p "###" rsync -avzPe myhost:/path/ /home/user/Downloads/rsync/tmp/ --time-limit=420 --bwlimit=7680 --remove-source-files --port=2100 --log-file=/home/user/Downloads/rsync/rsync.log
```

It doesn't create the empty directories that the remote server has, and it doesn't download the files in any of the directories. Is there something I am missing about the arguments I am passing? The whole point of this is to download files into a temporary directory, then when the files are done; move the files into the completed folder instead of a temporary directory.

Thanks in advance if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man rsync`:

```
 --rsh=COMMAND, -e        specify the remote shell to use
```

You don't seem to be specifying the shell in your command, instead you are telling rsync to use `myhost:/path/` as the remote shell.

By adding `-e "ssh -p 2100"` it should work.

**Full command:**

```
rsync -avzP -e "ssh -p 2100" myhost:/path/ /home/user/Downloads/rsync/tmp/ --time-limit=420 --bwlimit=7680 --remove-source-files --log-file=/home/user/Downloads/rsync/rsync.log
```

Note that you might want to use key based authentication instead of putting the password in your command.

Note that you should be **really carefull** with the `--remove-source-files` option and only use it if you are absolutely sure what you are doing.

Comment: I read that the `-e` command uses SSH by default (as I understood it at least). So that's why I pass my SSH password first in the command before running rsync. If I remove the `-e` argument it doesn't connect at all, sadly. And regarding the file removal, yes. The files I'm syncing is just a copy from another location.

Comment: Okay never mind. Looks like i f'ed up. You're right. It still doesn't connect. But it tells me after 5 minutes that it timed out. Little weird it still uses port 22 even though I pass the `--port` argument though.

Comment: `--port` is not for the ssh port AFAIK. I'll write you a solution real quick

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. Yea, I will look into using a key instead of plain password. Thanks again.